# Null pointer exception in AndEngine SoundManager

Tags: android, andengine

I just coded the following lines copied from AndExample.

```
try {
        this.collision_sound = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), this, "touch.ogg");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Error","in creation "+e);
    }

this.collision_sound.play();
```

Now The problem is that when i play the sound it gives me a null pointer exception. Any one can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be fine. Try to put the createsound function in the onLoad() method of AndEngine and call the play() method in another place. I suppose you're not giving the time to the engine to set up the sound variable.

Comment: I have already initialized the sound in onLoadEngine.Previously it was in OnLoadResources. Unfortunately the result is same. There is no error in creation but when I play the sound there is a NullPointerException. What should I do now?

Comment: Well, I've never used before .ogg files. Just to try, use a generic .mp3 and try again. Besides, post your logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the point where the problem was. Actually the above code is right what I was missing is that when I was creating the engine I was missing to set it options for sounds in on load engine like.

```
new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera).setNeedsSound(true));
```

this solved my problem I was missing the .setNeedsSound(true) option.